# How to group a bunch of lists by a key to a single dictionary in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, grouping

I have a bunch of lists that contain elements that are related to each other and I want to convert them to a single dictionary with lists as values:

```
list1 = ['cat', 'animal']
list2 = ['dog', 'animal']
list3 = ['crow', 'bird']

result = {'animal': ['cat', 'dog'], 'bird': 'crow'}
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simple approach:**

```
data = [['cat', 'animal'], ['dog', 'animal'], ['crow', 'bird']]

result = {}

for value, key in data:
    result[key] = result.get(key, []) + [value]

result #=> {'bird': ['crow'], 'animal': ['cat', 'dog']}
```

**Using `defaultdict`:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [['cat', 'animal'], ['dog', 'animal'], ['crow', 'bird']]

result = defaultdict(list)

for value, key in data:
    result[key].append(value)

result #=> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'animal': ['cat', 'dog'], 'bird': ['crow']})
```

**Using `groupby` from `itertools`:**

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [['cat', 'animal'], ['dog', 'animal'], ['crow', 'bird']]

{k: [x[0] for x in g] for k, g in groupby(data, lambda x: x[1])}
#=> {'bird': ['crow'], 'animal': ['cat', 'dog']}
```

**Using `reduce` from `functools`:**

```
from functools import reduce

data = [['cat', 'animal'], ['dog', 'animal'], ['crow', 'bird']]

reduce(lambda a, e: dict(a, **{e[1]: a.get(e[1], []) + [e[0]]}), data, {})
#=> {'bird': ['crow'], 'animal': ['cat', 'dog']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help i ended up using the defaultdict approach which worked perfectly and the other approaches are very interesting too.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of lists that you want to convert, you can do this:

```
dict1 = {}
for li in lists:

   if(li[1] not in dict1):
      dict1[li[1]] = []

   dict1[li1].append(li[0])
```

Note that this will produce `dict1={'animal':['cat','dog'],'bird':['crow']}` instead of `dict1={'animal':['cat','dog'],'bird':'crow'}`, which is what you have in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `defaultdict` from the `collections` module.  It is part of the standard library and operates the same as a dictionary with the exception that if a new key is passed, it will create a new value (a list in this case) automatically

```
list1=['cat','animal']
list2=['dog','animal']
list3=['crow','bird']


from collections import defaultdict

# create a new dictionary where an unknown key will automatically
# add the key to the dictionary with a empty list as the value
d = defaultdict(list)

# iterate over your lists, updating the dictionary
for value, key in (list1, list2, list3):
    d[key].append(value)

d
# returns:
defaultdict(list, {'animal': ['cat', 'dog'], 'bird': ['crow']})
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that your lists consists of pairs where the first item is the value and the second is the key, you can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) constructed with lists and then just append the results.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
my_lists = [list1, list2, list3]
for my_paired_list in my_lists:
    v, k = my_paired_list
    dd[k].append(v)
>>> dict(dd)
{'animal': ['cat', 'dog'], 'bird': ['crow']}
```

If you don't want keys with only one element to be in a list (e.g. `'bird': ['crow']` should be `'bird': 'crow'`), then just convert the result:

```
new_result = {k: v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.iteritems()}
>>> new_result
{'animal': ['cat', 'dog'], 'bird': 'crow'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have tuple of lists or list of lists following coed will be suitable. If you have defined variables with lists, you can simply add all lists into one variable firstly and then process it with algorithm written below.

```
lists = ['cat','animal'],['dog','animal'],['crow','bird']
results = {}

for list in lists:
    if list[1] in results:
        results[list[1]].append(list[0])
        print('bingo')
    else:
        results[list[1]] = [list[0]]

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers using `defaultdict` don't exactly match your intended output.  Here's a version without `defaultdict` that does.

```
list1=['cat','animal']
list2=['dog','animal']
list3=['crow','bird']

dict1 = {}
for v, k in (list1, list2, list3):
    if k in dict1:
        # If the value already exists (as string), convert it to list
        # and append the new value
        dict1[k] = [dict1[k]]
        dict1[k].append(v)
    else:
        # Otherwise, we just want a string, not list
        dict1[k] = v

print(dict1)
{'animal': ['cat', 'dog'], 'bird': 'crow'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merely iterate over a nested list of original data and use a `OrderedDict` to retain the order of entry:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = [
  ['cat', 'animal'],
  ['dog', 'animal'],
  ['crow', 'bird']
]

d = OrderedDict()

for name, type in data:
   if type in d:
      d[type].append(name)
   else:
      d[type] = [name]
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('animal', ['cat', 'dog']), ('bird', ['crow'])])
```